# OpenERP 6.1 debugging: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to debug OpenERP 6.1 on Windows 7 x64. I have Python 2.7 x86 installed, and when I try to run it from Eclipse I get the trace below. I have tried using the 32bit version of Eclipse as well.

I am able to debug OpenERP 6.0.3 though.

Any ideas? How do I know what module is trying to use Python 2.6? (I'm new to python and Eclipse.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Downloads\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.4.0.2012020116\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 3, in <module>
import pydev_imports
  File "E:\Downloads\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.4.0.2012020116\pysrc\pydev_imports.py", line 14, in <module>
from _pydev_SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
  File "E:\Downloads\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.4.0.2012020116\pysrc\_pydev_SimpleXMLRPCServer.py", line 115, in <module>
import SocketServer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 132, in <module>
import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

The output sys.path as asked for by Fabio:

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\Lib
C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywebdav-0.9.4.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vobject-0.8.1c-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
E:\Projects\openerp-6.1-1
```

When run from PyDev I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\openerp-6.1-1\test_output.py", line 3, in <module>
import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing here would be taking out the debugger out of it just to see the error:

Create a new file solely with:

```
import sys
print '\n'.join(sorted(sys.path))
import socket
```

run it from PyDev and add the full output to your question...

Comment: Your answer helped me track down what was wrong. The project properties had an external library pointing to the installation directory of OpenERP. Removing that fixed the problem. Thank you Fabio!